# Find limit for function such that $f(x)>0$ if $x<c$ and $f(x)<0$ if $x>c$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $c\in \mathbb R$. define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)>0$ if  $x<c$ and $f(x)<0$ if $x>c$. Find $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L}$ for some $L \in \mathbb R$.

My attempt:

Since we are asked to find the limit of the function, it means that limit for both $x<c$ and $x>c$ exists and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)}=\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)}$.

$f(x)>0$ for $x<c$ implies that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\alpha}$ such that $\alpha>0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.
Similarily, $f(x)<0$ for $x>c$ implies that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\beta}$ such that $\beta<0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Then, we get $0<\alpha=\beta<0.$ Hence $L=0$.

Comment: For the equiality $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)}=\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)}$ you need $f$ to be continuos, but as the problem is write it look this is the case. If his hipotesis is true, then your demo in correct.

Comment: $\alpha\ge 0$ and $ \beta\le 0$.

Comment: The way this problem is worded, you are supposed to define a particular function $f$ with the required properties, and (very awkwardly stated even for this interpretation) converging at $c$ to some real number $L$. So you could just define $f(x) = c - x$, and note that its limit at $c$ is $0$. What you have done is interpreted the problem as "Suppose $f$ is a function with $f(x) > 0$ for $x<c, f(x) < 0$ for $x > c$, and $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)= L \in \Bbb R$, Find $L$". But saying "Define $f$" does not mean the same thing as "Suppose $f$".

Comment: @PaulSinclair the question itself was worded with "let $f$ be", then would my attempt be valid? Thank you in advance.